# Django get fields of the ForeignKey Model efficiently?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am using django-rest-framework as backend and react as a frontend

For example if I have the following tables in Django

```
class Master1(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    field3 = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

class Master2(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    field3 = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

class Transaction(models.Model):
    master1 = models.ForeignKey(Master1)
    master2 = models.ForeignKey(Master2)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

I want to create a view for the Trasaction that displays several fields from each of its related models in frontend. Can someone suggest an efficient way of doing that.

Should I just define the fields it needs in the view or should I use nested serializers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`depth`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization) functionality to load data from `Master1/Master2` models from serializer:

```
class TransactionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = "__all__"
        depth = 1
```

And to load these FK data efficiently from DB, use [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related). For example:

```
queryset = Transaction.objects.select_related('master1', 'master2')
data = TransactionSerializer(queryset, many=True).data
```

Comment: The depth property is basically nesting the serializations of the ForeignKey fields right?

Comment: Thanks, can you also look at this link, its another question I asked. Kind of related to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64482884/design-database-efficiently-with-several-relations-django-postgresql